# How can i run Android app with eclipse with Webview on local website

Tags: android, eclipse, model-view-controller, webview

I have a android app project in Eclipse, and in my activity containing a Webview
i want to browse to a website that is on a local url, like http://localhost:8080/MyMVCProject/.
But what i have understand is that localhost on a Webview in a app is local on the device not on 
the webb. So my question is, How can i run a MVC project in the background on a 
specific url like http://localhost:8080.... and from my project in Eclipse in the webview
get that MVC page from local?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this you can use `10.0.2.2`.

See here for more info:
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses